# Version of Windows Phone 8.1 Incorrect in store

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows, windows-store

Since submitting a Windows Phone 8.1 app alongside our Windows Phone 8 I've noticed some strange behaviour in the store regarding app version numbers. In my AppManifest and when I'm building packages for the store I set a version number say, 2.0.2.1.

The package uploads fine but when visible in the store and on the upload page the version number has changed to when I built the package, for example v2015.918.xxxxx = 18/9/2015. I guess this is fine as it will keep getting larger but I still rather show the actual version number.

Thanks to an automated Twitter account I've noticed it happening to other apps too: https://twitter.com/NewsCuriosityWP/status/646956803079700480

I'd love to know why this happening, a bug with the store maybe?

Here are some examples:

[image: App upload page]
[image: Store display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem too, I posted about it in the forums: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2913ad6-6130-45b6-8a7f-086ff7f04cff/problem-with-version-number?forum=wpsubmit

Apparently it is working as intended ... but when I ported an app to Win10 UWP, it really messed up the version numbers and now I have to specify a version starting with 2015.... :-(

If you want to avoid this for new applications, you can prevent it from creating an app bundle, and then it should use the version number you specified.
Unfortunately, for already published app you cannot go back from app bundling

Hope this helps...

Comment: Great, thanks for this. Microsoft should really fix this.